# NAT/Firewall traversal with Java and the ICE (interactive connectivity establishment) protocol

Tags: java, stun, turn, nat-traversal

My goal is in fact very simple. I want to create java p2p connections over the Internet. With this connection I want to do audio/video chat. I know there are enough solutions for this out there but I need my own. The best would be a working libary for it with good source code, examples, docu and tutorials. But all of that is nearly impossible to find. I searched for nearly 1 week now for a solution and only find libaries that use ICE, STUN and TURN. But I need working examples oc connection establishment in java and found nearly nothing. Hope you understand my problem so that I can fast go on with building efficent p2p connections like skype ;)

UpNp is not an option because many routers dont support it. Solutions I already found but I could not get to work: ice4j, stunt, stun4j, jxta and the most promising one for me icedjava: https://java.net/projects/siptools/pages/IcedJava

Thank you so much!

Comment: Try JSTUN - http://jstun.javawi.de/

Comment: Do you know a good and working example of JSTUN?

Comment: http://www.stunprotocol.org/StunTask.java - this is a hacked up piece of code demonstrating the use of JSTUN on Android. Not production code - use at your own risk - but works well enough to demonstrate how to use JSTUN.

Comment: But as you read in my question I need a working ICE libary with good source code, examples, docu and tutorials. STUN alone is not enough.

Comment: Skype wasn't built in a week either.  :)  Start small and build up from there.

Comment: Therefore I want to use an existing ICE libary because I don't have to invent the wheel again... I really ONLY need a working ICE libary with good source code, examples, docu and tutorials.

Comment: What library did you end up going with ?

Comment: Might this library help you. Check [ice4j.org](http://code.google.com/p/ice4j/)